# How to pull data from SqlDataAdapter and store it in a JsonStore collection in MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I have a `SqlDataAdapter` and I want to store it in a JsonStore collection in MobileFirst and Display it in table form. I have tried using `Load()` method but its not working.
this is my resultSetCollection.js file

```
;(function () {

WL.JSONStore.init({
    resultSet : {
        searchFields: {"EMP_NAME":"string","EMP_ID":"integer"}
    }
}, {
    // password : 'PleaseChangeThisPassword'
})

.then(function () {

     return WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
          adapter : 'EmployeeList',
          procedure : 'getEmployeeLists',
          parameters : []
        }); 
})
.then(function (responseFromAdapter) {

     alert('responseFromAdapter:' + JSON.stringify(responseFromAdapter.invocationResult.resultSet));
     var accessor = WL.JSONStore.get('resultSet');
     var data=responseFromAdapter.invocationResult.resultSet;
     var changeOptions = {
                replaceCriteria : ['EMP_ID', 'EMP_NAME'],
                addNew : true,
                markDirty : false
              };

    return accessor.change(data, changeOptions);
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    //Here I want to retrieve the collection and display it in a table
})
.fail(function (errObj) {
    WL.Logger.ctx({pretty: true}).error(errObj);
});
```

}());

Comment: **SHOW US** some code!! How on earth are we supposed to help you, if you're **NOT SHOWING US ANYTHING**!?!??!?!? We cannot read your screen - nor your mind - you'll have to show us what you have and explain what you're doing and what doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

An adapter procedure request from a client application will have a response object in its success and failure callbacks. So lets assume that the request was successfull and data was returned from the backend server.

Lets also assume you have a JSONStore initialized and properly setup with a collection. You then only need to get the collection and add data to it.

The below example takes the full response from an HTTP adapter request and puts it as-is into a collection. You will of course need to create a better setup for your specific scenario...

Note that the code is *not optimised* and performance or with 100% proper logic. It's just a demonstration flow.

Tested in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0.0.00.
**main.js:**

```
var collectionName = 'mydata';
var collections = {
    mydata : {
        searchFields : {data: 'string'},
    }
};

function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(
        function() {
            var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/myadapter/getStories", WLResourceRequest.GET);
            resourceRequest.send().then(resourceRequestSuccess, resourceRequestFailure);
        }
    );  
}

function resourceRequestSuccess(response) {
    WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(response).then(
        function(){
            WL.Logger.info("successfully added response to collection");
            displayDataFromCollection();
        }, 
        function() {
            alert("failed adding response to collection");
        }
    );
}

function resourceRequestFailure() {
    alert ("failure");
}
```

If you then like to fetch the data from the JSONStore and display it in the HTML, you could do something like this:

```
// get a specific item from the stored response and display it in a table
function displayDataFromCollection() {
    WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).findAll().then(
        function(result) {
            $("#mytable").append("<tr><td>" + result[0].json.responseJSON.rss.channel.title + "</td></tr>");
        }, 
        function() {
            alert ("unable to display collection");
        }
    );
}
```

The **index.html** looks like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
</table>
```

Comment: How can i display this collection in tabular format and What if i want to invoke Sql Adapter not Http Adapter?

Comment: You do not put the collection in a table, you display the response in a table. You need to get the data from inside the collection - this data, the response from the adapter... is a JSON object, so you simply need to pick the specific data you would like to display, and use plain regular JavaScript to append it the desired element in the HTML. Find the time to learn JavaScript as well as read the JSONStore documentation.

Comment: @HyderAli, If this answer helped you, please mark as Answered.